# file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error - Login Error

Tags: magento2, login, ssl, magento2.2.7, ssl-certificate

After submitting the email and password getting the below error. Kindly help me with this. As per the error login below is the error

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14095126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading in /home/decure/public_html/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php on line 72
```

Comment: did you get a fix on it facing same issue

Comment: i have this issue too, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Please enabled php extension fopen().
And restart the server once. 
After that it will be work.

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Did you enabled this ? And also restart the apache?

Comment: yes, enabled & restarting the apache server

Comment: Please flush the cache and do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Its an openssl problem caused by upgrading to openssl 1.1.1e ( or on cpanel servers to ea-openssl11-1.1.1e ).

Either need to upgrade to openssl 1.1.1f , or downgrade to previous version ( 1.1.1d ) until other fixes are available

Links :

- https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11381
- https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11378
- https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360046193193-ea-openssl-1-1-1e-throws-an-error-on-some-HTTPS-sites?flash_digest=4379ced8bdb4f39beb6f5bde73a8f65db40f86cf

Answer (score 0):

On a cPanel/WHM powered servers do:

`$yum info ea-openssl11`

If you see `Version     : 1.1.1e` do the

`$yum downgrade ea-openssl11`

to get `Version     : 1.1.1d` back.

You may need to restart PHP-FPM service.

Reference: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/openssl-errors-in-php-scripts-after-upgrade-to-86-0-17.669905/

Answer (score 0):

From inside WHM you can now upgrade openssl to version 1.1.1f manually.

In terminal,
 $yum upgrade ea-openssl11

Once completed,
 $yum info ea-openssl11
 to ensure you have installed Release 1.1.1f

You will then need to restart PHP-FPM Service in WHM